How to format a Number to add two decimal points to existing number
How do turn this number:
2499 to 24.99
I attempted:


const qty = 2499;
console.log(qty.toFixed(2));



and I get 2499.00

Divide by 100 ?

Divide it by 100.



const qty = 2499 / 100;
console.log(qty.toFixed(2));




const qty = 2499;
const decimal = qty / 100;




const qty = 2499;
console.log((qty / 100).toFixed(2));



